# Splitview controller error in ios 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new to iPhone development. I am working on a project having split view controllers. What I am doing is as follows

```
[self.splitViewController removeFromParentViewController];
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     UINavigationController *detailViewNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:SampleViewController];

   self.nextSplitControler=[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    self.nextSplitControler.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController,detailViewNav, nil];
    self.nextSplitControler.delegate=SampleViewController;
    self.window.rootViewController=self.nextSplitControler;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

It works fine on iOS 5.0 . But on iOS 4.3 it throws an error as

`-[UISplitViewController removeFromParentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.`

Can any one help me with this issue? I am banging my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bang your head; check the docs.  :)

`- (void)removeFromParentViewController`

**Availability**

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: oK Thanks. Is there any other way to remove the split view controller in ios 4. i.e what approach i can follow in my case

Comment: I'm not sure.  Since there is no similar support for custom container controllers (therefore no `addChildViewController:`), I don't know what you'd be removing it from.  The code you have doesn't specify what the parent controller is even for iOS 5.

Comment: my parent controller is the window. i.e  self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

Comment: sorry for the lack of knowledge

Comment: The window isn't a view controller.  Setting the root controller can work just fine but it's not related to the `removeFromParentViewController` method in any way.  (The new parent/child relationship is for people who want to write their own controller that manages other view controllers.)

Comment: This is what I do.                        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

Comment: I see that, but the question was about `removeFromParentViewController` in iOS 4, which I'm now thinking may not have any actual purpose in your app for **any** iOS version.

Comment: I am doing this because my detail view gets changed every time I select each item in Master View .Without removing the splitView controller and replacing it with new one my splitview controller delegate methods woudn't be called